# html table fit column width to content

Tags: html, css

I would like my table column width fit to its content. Right now I got a super wide column[0], and the rest columns have fit width.

Why is this happening and how do I get the output I need?

Thanks.

[image]

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

<style>
    /*table {*/
        /*table-layout: auto;*/
        /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
        /*width: 100%;*/
    /*}*/
    /*table td {*/
        /*border: 1px solid #ccc;*/
    /*}*/
    table td.absorbing-column {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>


<h1>Query Results</h1>
<?PHP
    $keys = array_keys(get_object_vars($results[0]));
    echo "<table class=\"table table-bordered table-condensed\"><tr><th>".implode("</th><th>", $keys)."</th></tr>";
?>
    @foreach ($results as $result)
        <tr>
            @foreach ($keys as $key)
                <td class="absorbing-column">
                    {{$result->$key}}
                </td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
@endsection
```

Comment: Because you set the width to 100% on one of  the cells? Also, post the HTML, not the PHP or whatever that is.

Comment: CSS width in percentage refers to the width relative to the parent, not the content.

Answer (score 0):

You have the table width set to 100%. Try bringing it down to a lower percentage or use px.

Answer (score 0):

Completely remove the following CSS:

```
table td.absorbing-column {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This CSS is giving each `<td>` a width of 100%. If you remove it, the cedll width will be more evenly spaced, since your content is of similar width.

If you want your table itself to be the full width of its container, also add some different CSS, which you seem to have commented out:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Still a lot of space in table cells

Comment: Can you post the HTML that is output?

Comment: If you're looking for the table to be the width of the content, and not the width of its container, then remove the last CSS that I added: `table { width: 100% }`. Then, as long as neither the `td` nor the `table` have a width defined, then the cells and table itself will be the width of the content. If that's not what you're looking for, please describe what you want to happen, and post the HTML that your PHP is outputting.